# Cannot open Android Studio from terminal

Tags: windows, android-studio, ionic-framework, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an Ionic project and I wanted to setup a kind of live reload for android emulator. But when I run `ionic capacitor run android -l --external`, I don't see any available devices, despite that they're connected. [image]

I guess it is related to that Ionic can't spot location of the Android Studio executable, because when I then try to run `ionic cap open android`, I just see the folowing without having the android IDE opened:
[image]

I also tried to set the `CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH` env variable but it still doesn't help:

[image]

Has anybody faced such a problem? For those who wondering, I'm using WSL (Ubuntu-20.04) and Windows 11. I also tried to install the Android Studio directly to the WSL but it didn't have any success.